# where anidado en laravel

Tags: laravel

necesito hacer una consulta donde me filtren por un where, y de ese resultado sacar solo los registros que almenos uno de los campos cumpla con el like,no he podido hacerlo en laravel

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE documentable_id=2 and documentable_type= 'App\Models\Topic' and role is null and ('title' like '%pre%' or 'description' like '%pre%' or 'references' like '%pre%')
```

esa es mi consulta

ya intente de la siguiente manera y no me funciona

```
 $query = DB::table('document')
    ->where([
    ['documentable_id', 2],
    ['documentable_type', 'App\Models\Topic'],
    ])

    ->orWhere([
    ['name', 'like', '%pre%'],
    ['description', 'like', '%pre%'],
    ])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

De hecho tu consulta no está bien, le faltan paréntesis, pero tu consulta final en laravel quedaría como:

```
$query = DB::table('document')
    ->where([
    ['documentable_id', 2],
    ['documentable_type', 'App\Models\Topic'],
    ])

    ->where(function($q){
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%pre%')
          ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%pre%')
          ->orWhere('references', 'like', '%pre%');
     })->get();
```